# Implementing a friends list in Symfony2.1 with Doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.1

I want to implement friends list of particular user in `Symfony2.1` and `Doctrine.`
Lets say friends table:

```
User1 User2 Status     //0-pending request,1-accepted
A     B      0
A     C      1
D     A      1
E     A      1
```

Now I want to get `A`'s friends name in the list. For this `SQL` query can be implemented using `UNION` as read in many other answers. But I want to implement this in `doctrine query builder.`
One option is like query separately for two columns and combine the result and sort. But this takes more time to execute and get result. I want to get quick response as soon as possible. Is there any way to query it?

Comment: This is not really the optimal way of implementing a friendslist, since your "friendship" object will then have a direction (which will cause you to write lots of conditionals in queries later on). Consider implementing a `Friendship` <M:N> `User` association instead, with each friendship having exactly 2 user (constrained at application level)

Comment: Ya that is right! Already @JeanValjean mentioned that.But I want to keep status like request pending or accepted.So I implemented this way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You don't need any additional effort**, e.g. by using Doctrine Query Builder!

Simply design the entity class `User` to have a [many-to-many self-reference with User](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-self-referencing), e.g.:

```
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class User
{
....

    /**
     * @var string $name
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", unique=true, length=255)
     * 
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="myFriends")
     **/
    private $friendsWithMe;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="friendsWithMe")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="friends",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="friend_user_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     **/
    private $myFriends;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->friendsWithMe = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->myFriends = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

}
```

Then you can simply get the User entity and obtains all the friends as follows:

```
$user = $this->getDoctrine()
                ->getRepository('AcmeUserBundle:User')
                ->findOneById($anUserId);
$friends = $user->getMyFriends();
$names = array();
foreach($friends as $friend) $names[] = $friend->getName();
```

Comment: Actually I created separate table for friends as I wanted to store status like pending request,accepted etc.Because of that I have to take this trouble.Any idea to implement this?

Comment: If there are multiple status types you must define separated tables and you cannot insert that flags in the  friedlist table. So, you should avoid to create an additional table. Also consider that doctrine will automatically create a table like yours when mapping the many-to-many association that I provided.

Comment: There is only one status type like pending request will change to accepted. I edited the top table format.I want to implement like that.My requirement is to add extra column 'Status' to automatically created table by Doctrine

Comment: The example seems to be still wrong to me. You are mixing concepts that must be kept separated! One thing is the friend list, from which you get the friends name. Please, implement this feature as I proposed. Another thing is a table with (temporary) data: this table name should be "invitation" and not "friendlist". Invitation has the following columns:  _sender_ (type user), _receiver_ (type user), _status_ (type boolean), plus other additional fields like _sendingdate_. In this way you have a more efficient implementation and you gurantee separation between two different business logic!

Comment: okay.This actually looks good.But I can't change table structure now as it has dependency.Without changing table structure is there any way to implement this?

Comment: A preliminary remarks: you can always change. Answering your question, yes, there is more than one way. But, to answer your question, you have to explain when one is friend of another. Are the users in column UserA friends to users in column UserB such as status=1 and vice versa? In other words, I need to know if the table must be read in both directions or not!

Comment: ya.It is both directions.In above example E -> A is equal to A -> E. Not separate records.

Comment: A Doctrine query should be something like the following DQL query: "SELECT DISTINCT l.friend FROM AcmeBundlenameBundle:FriendList l JOIN l.usera a JOIN l.userb b WHERE l.status=1 AND (a.id = $id OR b.id=$id")"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24185/discussion-between-stefun-and-jeanvaljean)

Comment: Is there any way to add extra fields to the joined table such as created_at?