# Implementing a friends relationship in Symfony3 with Doctrine

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony

according to the post [Implementing a friends list in Symfony2.1 with Doctrine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14753228/implementing-a-friends-list-in-symfony2-1-with-doctrine/37795706#37795706),
i implemented the solution of @Roberto Trunfio.

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="friends")
 */
private $friendsWithMe;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="friendsWithMe")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="friends",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="friend_user_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 */
private $friends;
```

It works, however I would like to go further by adding extra fields like 'senders, receiver, status, sendingDate...' but I don't know how to integrate it. Can somebody help me please ? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to decorate the association with additional attributes, you need an association class. [From the documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-unidirectional) (scroll down a bit):

> Why are many-to-many associations less common? Because frequently you want to associate additional attributes with an association, in which case you introduce an association class. Consequently, the direct many-to-many association disappears and is replaced by one-to-many/many-to-one associations between the 3 participating classes.

The association class in your example is *friendship*. A user can have many friends and a user can be the friend of many users. Or more technically: A user has many friendships and many friendships map to a friend. In the example given below, `Friendship` has the additional attribute `$hasBeenHelpful` (which is unsymmetrical indeed).

```
// src/AppBundle/Entity/User.php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * The people who I think are my friends.
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Friendship", mappedBy="user")
     */
    private $friends;

    /**
     * The people who think that I’m their friend.
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Friendship", mappedBy="friend")
     */
    private $friendsWithMe;

    // …
}
```

And the friendship association:

```
// src/AppBundle/Entity/Friendship.php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Friendship
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="friends")
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="friendsWithMe")
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    private $friend;

    /**
     * Example of an additional attribute.
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    private $hasBeenHelpful;

    // …
}
```

You probably want to add some functions to the User class, such as

```
<?php

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

class User
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->friends = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->friendsWithMe = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function addFriendship(Friendship $friendship)
    {
        $this->friends->add($friendship);
        $friendship->friend->addFriendshipWithMe($friendship);
    }

    public function addFriendshipWithMe(Friendship $friendship)
    {
        $this->friendsWithMe->add($friendship);
    }

    public function addFriend(User $friend)
    {
        $fs = new Friendship();
        $fs->setUser($this);
        $fs->setFriend($friend);
        // set defaults
        $fs->setHasBeenUseful(true);

        $this->addFriendship($fs);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. In my function for add friend I've got this error:
Type error: Argument 1 passed to AppBundle\Entity\User::addFriend() must be an instance of AppBundle\Entity\Friendship, instance of AppBundle\Entity\User given, called in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/equilike/src/AppBundle/Controller/Member/FriendController.php on line 35

Do you have any idea how I can fix it ?
(my friendship managing code is too long to add it in the comment)

Comment: Apparently, your FriendController calls `$user->addFriend($otherUser)`, but the signature is `addFriend(Friendship $fs)`. You can change the signature to `addFriend(User $friend)` and create a friendship object with default attributes inside this function. You should also add a function `addFriendship(Friendship $fs)`.

Comment: Hi, thanks. My add function is working now. However I think It's working like a "follow" function (like Twitter) and not like "friendship" (like Facebook).
Am I wrong ? Or should I reconsider the organisation of my entity associations ? Do you need more information about what I want to do ? Thanks for helping

Comment: @barmatt I think these considerations are beyond the scope of the original question. You might want to open another question asking about the differences of various friendship-like relationships (rather than how to implement them). Also, if you found my answer helpful, consider upvoting it. Thanks!

Comment: ok , I understand. I'm going to create a new post. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: This does not work, it causes `A new entity was found through the relationship... To solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity or configure cascade persist this association in the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}).` since it creates new entity on the fly within the Entity method. Adding the cascade options within `Friendship` entity does not seem to solve the problem either. On the other hand - adding it within the `User` class - does help.