# Relationship between User with Symfony3 Doctrine

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony

I'm a beginner on Symfony. 
I'm trying to create a friendship relation between users.
I was wondering which possible ways I could use ? By now I created this : [Implementing a friends relationship in Symfony3 with Doctrine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37797186/implementing-a-friends-relationship-in-symfony3-with-doctrine)

It works more as a follow function (like twitter) and I would like to find a way to create relationship like facebook.

I was thinking about an entity "invitation" with a minimum of fields: asking_date, status, accepting_date, blocked.

The problem is that I can't figured out the different associations to do between the entities?

Can somebody help me to go on the right track ?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: First off, you should give @Lumen an upvote for helping you out on your previous question. I'm sure he put in some time to give you that answer. Then secondly, you might want to post separate questions instead. You are asking for a lot of help, but you should also show some "effort" put into investigation by posting some code or something to show that effort.

Comment: @AlvinBunk thanks for your comment. I'm new here, I thought I did vote for Lumen's help. I'm not asking for a done code, just for the way to understand the method.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably good to draw this out in a diagram so you can think about the relationships and how they might work. I'm not sure if you are already familiar with Entity Relationship Diagrams (ER diagrams), but here is [a simple tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/dbms/er_diagram_representation.htm) that will get you started.

You can also do a search on Google for more info.
Get an ER Diagram drawn out and think about how those entities might work together. Doing the diagram first will help you find problems at the start, and will help figure out how you want the system to work.

Comment: Thank you for your time and your advice.

Comment: Always remember to upvote if you think suggestions are helpful at all. Thank you!